# Define domain of the function

Tags: functions

Is it right to determine the domain of the function $f(x) = (x - 2)(8 - x)$, $x\in\Bbb R$ as $D(f) = \{y\in\Bbb R \mid y \geq -9\}$?

$f(x) = x² - 10x + 16$
$\Delta  = 36$ $\therefore$ $x_1 = 8$, $x_2 = 2$
Vertex of a Parabola = $(5, -9)$

Comment: What is $\Delta$?

Comment: I just remembered $\Delta$ is the discriminant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When given an expression $f(x)$ we say the *domain* $D(f)$ of $f(x)$ is the collection of all $x$ where the expression $f(x)$ is valid. In other words, $D(f)$ is the collection of all $x$ that we are "allowed" to plug into $f(x)$.

For example, we would say the domain of 
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{x}
$$
is $D(g)=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\neq0\}$.

What $x$'s are we "allowed" to plug into $f(x)=(x-2)(8-x)$?

Comment: This function then `D(f) = R`?

Comment: Yes in this case $D(f)=\Bbb R$.